# How can I install Windows (10, probably) alongside my existing elementary OS?

Tags: microsoft-windows

Note that this is not about installing elementary OS (I already have a functional system that I would like to keep).  I simply want to install Windows alongside it.

My laptop is 64 bit, and UEFI (I think, but if someone knows how to check this that might be worthwhile).

Comment: I suggest: Install windows first then elementary

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a bit tricky. Once you install Windows alongside with Linux (or vice versa) you will mess up GRUB. So, the way I do it, and it is REALLY EASY, is:

1- Install the OS that you want. Don't mind GRUB for now. Install as many Windows as you want, as many Linux as you want (I have elementary and 3 Windows)

2- After the installation, boot ubuntu/elementary from the CD (or flash drive) and select "Try elementary/ubuntu".

3- Now you only have to download,install and run [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair). Use the "PPA" to install Boot-Repair (it will be the 2nd Option).

4- Remove the CD/flash drive and reboot your PC.

Answer (score 0):

Its probably better to install Windows first and then linux. But if you already have a linux system and want to dual boot with Windows then you can follow steps mentioned here: https://askubuntu.com/a/163249