# Install Windows 7 and erase Elementary OS

Tags: system-installation, microsoft-windows

I would like to try to use only Elementary OS for my dayli worklow, so I want to erase disk and insall Elementary OS. But just for safety reasons: Is it possible to install Windows 7 after that?

Best Regards, Niklas

Comment: 1. If you want to remove windows and install elementary, see [How can I erase everything when installing elementary OS?](http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/3816/how-can-i-erase-everything-when-installing-elementary-os). 2. To install windows later [the above link](http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/3779/how-can-i-install-windows-10-probably-alongside-my-existing-elementary-os).  _I suggest first install windows and then elementary_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's definitely possible to restore Windows 7 and remove Elementary. You'll need a Windows 7 restore disc to do so. One might have come with your computer. If you don't have one, you can create one:

1. Get your Windows 7 Installation disc or [download the ISO from Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows7).
2. Follow [these instructions](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/windows-usb-dvd-download-tool) to create a bootable recovery drive.

You'll need to do this before you remove Windows, of course.

When you boot into the Elementary install DVD/USB, you'll have the option to try Elementary before you install it. I'd recommend doing that to make sure everything works properly before you erase Windows. Enjoy! :)

Answer (score 1):

Of course it is possible Niklas and that too without any trouble., but since this is very newbie question, I would advise you to look into and understand the differences that all linux based distributions have from mainstream Windows so that your expectations are set accordingly. Elementary OS does make it really easy to use though!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to install windows after elementary install, you should make a repartition of your hard drive, and install windows on this partition you make.

Anyway, if you install windows after elementary, you will need to run elementary's live-CD to reinstall and update Grub because windows tend to break it.